# Unknown Column exception in Mysql 1054

Tags: mysql, pyqt

I tried all possible means. I included backQuotes for the string as suggested some in stack but nothing worked. It repeats the error as usual.
I also tried some queries that worked in other python files still it shows the same. I also tried queries with string without hyphens even it didn't work. I cant find out whats the problem here.

```
import MySQLdb
    import sys

    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

    qtCreatorFile = "Studisplay.ui"  # Enter file here.

    Ui_MainWindow1, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

    class stuDisplay(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1,QtGui.QTableWidget):
        def __init__(self,ID):
            #super(stuDisplay, self).__init__(parent)
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            Ui_MainWindow1.__init__(self)
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
            obj = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "1234567", "python")

            #The value of ID here is 14-VEC-244 I also tried `14-VEC-244` but did not work
            sql = 'SELECT MEMname FROM Borrowed WHERE MemberID ='+ str(ID)         

            cursor = obj.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
            name=cursor.fetchone()
            print name
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gautham/PycharmProjects/LIBALERT/Login.py", line 105, in
>   pushButton_clicked
>       self.call = StuSecond.stuDisplay(StuID)   File "/home/gautham/PycharmProjects/LIBALERT/StuSecond.py", line 22, in
>   **init**
>       cursor.execute(sql)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in
>   execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in
>   defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'VEC' in 'where clause'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string into your `WHERE` clause, so it must be quoted *within the query string that gets passed to the database*, something like so:

```
sql = "SELECT MEMname FROM Borrowed WHERE MemberID = '" + str(ID) + "'"
```

so that the finished string looks like

> sql = "SELECT MEMname FROM Borrowed WHERE MemberID = '14-VEC-244'"

(Note that the single quotes are "forward" quotes, not backticks.)

This would also be an excellent application for a prepared statement; unfortunately I am not familiar with pyqt and so cannot advise you there.